# Remove Runtime Checks compiler flag per-project in CMAKE

Tags: configuration, cmake

I have a CMAKE configuration where all my project configurations include the `/RTC1` (Both Runtime Checks) compiler flag. However, I wish to switch to the `Default` option for only one project, as it also has the `/clr` compiler flag; which is incompatible with the Runtime Checks flag. I'm relatively new to CMAKE, so this may have an obvious solution, but I've so far been unable to find this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I didn't manage to find a solution whereby I could nicely remove the particular options, but I did find a way of stripping the option from the compiler flags variable using a REGEX REPLACE:

```
STRING (REGEX REPLACE "/RTC(su|[1su])" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Where this may not be the most ideal approach, it has worked well in my situation where it is a special-cased scenario.

Comment: FWIW, I had to repeat this with the `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` and `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG`. I did this in a loop using [the pattern from SDL2's CMakeLists.txt here](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/release-2.0.3/CMakeLists.txt#L158).

Comment: My C/C++ flags had `/RTC1` and `-RTC1` populated. To remove both, I used `STRING (REGEX REPLACE "[/|-]RTC(su|[1su])" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")`

Answer (score 2):

I'd recently faced with the same problem and found no elegant solution. However this code does the job:

```
foreach(flag_var
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
        CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
    STRING (REGEX REPLACE "/RTC[^ ]*" "" ${flag_var} "${${flag_var}}")
endforeach(flag_var)
set_property(TARGET necessary_targets_here APPEND_STRING PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS " /RTC1")
```

If you only need to clear `/RTC` flag for one configuration (ex. Debug) you may try the following approach:

```
STRING (REGEX REPLACE "/RTC[^ ]*" "" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
foreach(target_var necessary_targets_here)
  target_compile_options(${target_var} PRIVATE $<$<CONFIG:Debug>: /RTC1>)
endforeach()
```

Please, note using [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>: /RTC1 >` which expands to `/RTC1` only in Debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are adding your flags with `add_definitions()`, then you can remove them with `remove_definitions`, see [documentation](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3aremove_definitions).

Also, you can play with [COMPILE_DEFINITIONS](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#prop_tgt%3aCOMPILE_DEFINITIONS) target property.

Comment: I tried using `remove_definitions`, but the original setting was set using `set (...)`, so `remove_definitions` didn't work. I ended up solving the issue using a REGEX REPLACE command.